# List with images in webpage

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a list in my webpage such that each item in the list is preceded by an icon. After a lot of trial I found that the best way to do it is by using css. Hence the css I am using is as follows.

```
ul#interest
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

li#interest_list
{
    background-image: url('../images/icons/lab.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

And the corresponding html is:

```
<h2>Interests</h2>
<hr class="styled-two"/>
<ul id="interest">
    <li id="interest_list">Cricket</li>
    <li id="interest_list">Football</li>
    <li id="interest_list">Table Tennis</li>
    <li id="interest_list">Voleyball and Hockey</li>
</ul>
```

I am getting the following output:

[image]

As you can see. All the text is pushed to the extreme right of the page.
The only way I can get it near the icon is by adding padding right:

```
li#interest_list
{
    background-image: url('../images/icons/lab.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*background-position: 100% .4em;*/
    padding-right: 185px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Which makes it look like this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: The text is aligned right because you have `text-align: right;` for `ul#interest`.  Just remove it if you want it aligned left, then add padding to the left instead.

Comment: Thanks davidpauljunior. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should change your li items to have class name instead of ids. You shouldn't have the same ids more than once.

```
<li class="interest_list">
```

Then in your css:

```
li.interest_list
```

Or if you'd rather not repeat yourself:

```
<ul id="interest">
  <li>Cricket</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

And the css selector becomes:

```
#interest li { ... }
```

As far as your spacing, it's because you have a property of text-align: right specified on the ul. Take that our and your text will no longer get pushed to the right side. You are going to want to add some padding to the left of the li elements so the text doesn't overlap the icon:

```
#interest li {
  background: url('../images/icons/lab.png') no-repeat left center;
  padding: 0 0 10px 30px;
}
```

Comment: Just removing text-align right makes the text overlap with the icon. As davidpauljunior suggested. Removing it and then adding padding-left works. Thnaks for the suggestion of using css selector. That slipped out of my mind.

Comment: See my last paragraph: padding: 0 0 10px 30px.. adds 30px of padding to the left of the li so that the icon won't get covered by the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
li#interest_list {
    background-image: url("../images/icons/lab.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Is this true?

As you want remove padding-right.

Answer (score 0):

The css is causing the text to align to the right. Use padding-left on the li objects instead. In addition, #id selectors can only be used to refer to single objects. Multiple items should use a .class selector.

updated CSS:

```
ul#interest
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li.interest_list
{
    background-image: url('../images/icons/lab.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px
}
```

updated HTML:

```
<h2>Interests</h2>
<hr class="styled-two"/>
<ul id="interest">
    <li class="interest_list">Cricket</li>
    <li class="interest_list">Football</li>
    <li class="interest_list">Table Tennis</li>
    <li class="interest_list">Voleyball and Hockey</li>
</ul>
```